# Determine the age of a session in django

Tags: django, session, django-views

How can I determine the age of a session object in django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's what I have come up with.  Much better.  I think this is as cheap as using post_save on a Session object is going to get:

```
from django.db import models
from people.models import Member
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore


from django.db.models import *
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete, post_init
from datetime import datetime

class SessionInfo(models.Model):
    #note: a OneToOneField with the name 'session' has been added as part of the inheritance
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #joined field is auto initialized with creation time
    session = models.OneToOneField(Session)
    def age(self):
        return (datetime.now() - self.created)


def session_create_listener(instance, **kwargs):
    store = SessionStore(session_key=instance.session_key)

    if '_auth_user_id' in store:
        try:
            instance.sessioninfo
        except SessionInfo.DoesNotExist:
            sessioninfo = SessionInfo(session=instance) 
            sessioninfo.save()        

post_save.connect(session_create_listener, sender=Session)
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to hook the post_init signal coming from django.contrib.sessions.models.Session to be notified of a session start (or end), and then save that info to a model in your own app. e.g.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.db.models import *
from django.db.models.signals import post_init, pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import datetime

class SessionTimer(Session):
    #note: a OneToOneField with the name 'session' has been added as part of the inheritance
    created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #joined field is auto initialized with creation time
    def age(self):
        return (datetime.now() - self.created)

@receiver(post_init, sender=Session)
def session_create_listener(instance, **kwargs):
    created_session = instance
    timer_entry = SessionTimer(session=created_session)
    timer_entry.save()

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Session)
def session_destroy_listener(instance, **kwargs):
    SessionTimer.objects.get(session=instance).delete() # short version
```

hence when you need to know the age of a session, use `session.sessiontimer.age()`. this will return a TimeDelta object representing the age of the session.

Comment: This code doesn't work, for a few reasons:  1) Of least import, "receiver" is spelled wrong in the decorator.  2) The function session_create_listener, when executing the .save() method, seems to actually save the Session, causing a recursive loop.  3) The object "created_session" ends up being "<class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>", not a Session instance.  Thus, ValueError is raised.

Comment: quite right you are, i was using session_create_listener(session, **kwargs)` instead of `session_create_listener(instance, **kwargs)`. Should be correct now.

Comment: Although this is viable and interesting code for those working toward a solution, it is not itself one.  Why are you using post_init instead of post_save?  Also, what do you intend to do about SessionTimer itself causing the signal to fire?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing instead of Thomas' suggestion.  Note that I declined to use the receiver decorator so that this will still work pre 1.3.

(This needs serious correction).

```
from django.db import models
from people.models import Member
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore


from django.db.models import *
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete, post_init
#from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import datetime

class SessionInfo(models.Model):
    #note: a OneToOneField with the name 'session' has been added as part of the inheritance
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #joined field is auto initialized with creation time
    session = models.OneToOneField(Session)
    def age(self):
        return (datetime.now() - self.created)


def session_create_listener(instance, **kwargs):
    store = SessionStore(session_key=instance.session_key)

    if '_auth_user_id' in store:
        try:
            sessioninfo = SessionInfo.objects.get(session=instance)
        except SessionInfo.DoesNotExist:
            sessioninfo = SessionInfo(session=instance) 
            sessioninfo.save()
            store['anonymous'] = False
            store.save()
    else:
        try:
            store['anonymous']
        except KeyError:
            store['anonymous'] = True 
            store.save()

post_save.connect(session_create_listener, sender=Session)
```

I hope that somebody can correct this for me, because I cannot believe that this is the most efficient way to do this.

First and foremost, this adds TWO extra database hits (in the first try: sessioninfo = SessionInfo.objects.get(session=instance)) every time a session is modified.

The first is obviously during the lookup.  The second happens when the save occurs, triggering the entire process again.

What to do instead?